# jQuery slide toggle minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div tag like this,

```
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
   <div id="box">
   </div>
</div>
```

I've written a JQuery function to minimize box, now I want the title bar also to be minimized to the bottom of my page so,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
        $("#title_bar").slideDown();
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
        $("#title_bar").slideUp();
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

but using this only box is getting minimized and maximized and the title_bar is disappearing completely, how do I achieve minimizing title_bar to the bottom of my page along with the box div?

I am trying to achive:

1. when `'-'` is clicked both the `#title_bar` and `#box` must be minimized to the bottom of the page and `'-'` should be changed to `'+'`
2. When `'+'` is clicked both `#title_bar` and #box must be maximized and `'+'` must me changed to `'-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click here for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cocoa_beans/F7w2S/1/) demo

HTML Code

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <span class='switch-icons'>-</span>
    <h2 class='title'>title bar</h2>
<div class='content'>
    the content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

JS`code

```
$('.switch-icons').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).html()==='-'){$(this).html('+');}
    else $(this).html('-')
    $('.title,.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing id selector (missing `#` in `$('title_bar')` )

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        return $.trim(html) == '-' ? '+' : '-'
    })
    $("#box, #title_bar").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EUp97/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `#` to select element with id `title_bar`.

You can also shorten your code to this:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html() == "-" ? "+" : "-");
    $("#box, #title_bar").slideToggle();
});
```

Also, you need to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html() == "-" ? "+" : "-");
        $("#box, #title_bar").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hel. the #title_bar and #box both are disappearing..How can we maximize them? I want the title_bar to be minimized to the end of the page.

Comment: Nope..I want the title bar to come to the bottom of the page but here it is disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

check this : http://jsfiddle.net/3T5fR/

you need to modify your JS like this :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "+"){
        $(this).html("-");
        $("#box").slideDown();
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("+");
        $("#box").slideUp();
    }    
});
```